# timedelta64[ns] -> FutureWarning: Passing timedelta64-dtype data is deprecated, will raise a TypeError in a future version

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot

Assuming `df['time']` is from type `timedelta64[ns]` and `df['a']` as well as `df['b']` are from type `float64`, the two series can be plotted like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)

time_values = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
axs[0].plot(time_values, df['a'])
axs[1].plot(time_values, df['b'])
plt.show()
```

This works.. But gives the following Warning:

```
FutureWarning: Passing timedelta64-dtype data is deprecated, will raise a TypeError in a future version
```

So what should be used instead of `pd.to_datetime` to display `timedelta64[ns]` as human-readable time in `matplotlib`?

Comment: `pd.to_timedelta`?

Comment: @QuangHoang `import pandas as pd`

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue when reading time data from SQL using pandas. These 2 lines solved my problem. I tried to find another direct solution without success.

```
time_values = df['time'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if pd.isnull(x) else str(x)[-8:])
time_values = pd.to_datetime(time_values, format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time
```